# Can I iterate through a dictionary using all items in a comboBox?

Tags: c#

I tried asking the question earlier but didn't explain well enough. I will try again, I have a dictionary that gets and sets string for an image and List the gets string. The dictionary items are stored in a listBox, when I double click an item it sets to another comboBox. I want to click a button that will iterate through the dictionary and if they match anything in the dictionary it will store in a listView. I don't want the images though just the string name and price, here is the class and dictionary:

```
    class BookTitle
    {
        public string ImageTitle { get; set; }
        public List<string> Prices { get; }

        public BookTitle(string imageTitle, params string[] prices)
        {
            ImageTitle = imageTitle;
            Prices = new List<string>(prices.Length);
            Prices.AddRange(prices);
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, BookTitle> prices = new Dictionary<string, BookTitle>
    {
        { "Visual Basic", new BookTitle("vb.png", "$55") },
        { "Java", new BookTitle("java.png", "$45") },
        { "C#", new BookTitle("c#.png", "$75") },
        { "LAN Networks", new BookTitle("lan.png", "$68") },
        { "Windows Networking", new BookTitle("windows.png", "$49") },
        { "More About Networking", new BookTitle("more.png", "$54") },
        { "Web Programming", new BookTitle("web.png", "$67") },
        { "JavaScript", new BookTitle("javascript.png", "$64") },
        { "ASP", new BookTitle("asp.png", "$50") }
    };
```

Do you guys think I should just make a new class? I have tried this among many others:

```
    private void finalizeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cartItems = cartComboBox.Items.ToString();

        if (prices.Keys.Contains(cartItems))
        {
            BookTitle bt = prices[cartItems];
            ListViewItem list = cartListView.Items.Add(cartItems);
            list.SubItems.Add(cartItems);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way,

```
    private void finalizeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var cmbObj in cartComboBox.Items)
            {
                if (prices.Keys.Contains(cmbObj.ToString()))
                {
                     BookTitle tempOut;
                     ListViewItem list = 
                     cartListView.Items.Add(cmbObj.ToString());
                    if (prices.TryGetValue(cmbObj.ToString(), out tempOut))
                        list.SubItems.Add(tempOut.Prices[0].ToString());

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: This works for the Text in the comboBox great, I am still trying to pull the string value ($55) and store in SubItems as well.

Answer (score 1):

@Sajeetharan I will accept your answer because it was very helpful and got me on the right track.I ended up doing this:

```
    private void finalizeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var comboItem in cartComboBox.Items)
        {
            if (prices.Keys.Contains(comboItem.ToString()))
            {
                BookTitle bt = prices[comboItem.ToString()];
                ListViewItem list = cartListView.Items.Add(comboItem.ToString());
                foreach (var p in bt.Prices)
                {
                    list.SubItems.Add(p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I am still noobish and couldn't upvote a minute ago. Thank you!

Comment: Also would you suggest your code over mine? if so why? I am just trying to learn what I can!

Comment: your code is better in this case, what i written was to pick the item from the dictionary and take the 0th element of the price

Comment: Oh I see, thank you again. This had me stumped for a couple hours.